# Excel - Sum assigned numeric value of 1 to different phrases in different cells in a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm assessing a survey of multiple choice answers using Excel.  I need to assign a numeric value of 1 to fixed text answers and show the sum on another worksheet in the same workbook (the text is selected from a menu, so the strings are always precise).  Incorrect answers (text that does not match the specifically worded correct answer or blank cells) are to be assigned 0 and not be included in the final score.

Example:

Cell A2 should have the worded answer "My dog has fleas" and C2 should have "So does the cat". Cells A2 and C2 should sum to a total score of 2. There are 10 cells that should have correct answers, all differently worded.

I have tried  =IF('worksheet name'!AD2:AT2="My Dog Has Fleas","So Does The Cat","Grooming",1,0).  I have tried other variations of =IF, IFS and a variety of SUMIFS, all without success.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Since this is not a script / formula writing service, there is a reasonable expectation for you to have attempted something already. Please clarify what you have researched and/or attempted so far. Including the formula you are already working with would be helpful.

Comment: Is this text selected from a menu (so the entry is guaranteed to match exactly)?  If not, is text that has a typo, different capitalization, an extra space, etc. not a match, or do you need to do a fuzzy match?

Comment: You could still get additional answers that contain other useful approaches.  It's better to keep your question as just the actual question (plus any clarifications).  Use comments for responses to answers that aren't clarifications of the question.

Answer (score 1):

A tiny trick:
A formula like:

```
=(A2="My dog has fleas")
```

will return either **True** or **False**

a formula like:

```
=--(A2="My dog has fleas")
```

will return either **1** or **0**

so you can use something like

```
=--(A2="My dog has fleas")--(C2="So does the cat")
```

one term for each cell to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

You are headed in the right direction. The `IF` function returns a given result depending on the logical evaluation. It does not add those values for you. So, you need to combine `SUM` and `IF`.

*Note: there are other sophisticated ways to do this, but I am using this form because it is close to what you are working with so far.*

To check each text you will need it's own `IF` statement like this;

```
IF(Sheet1!A2="My dog has fleas.", 1, 0)
```

and

```
IF(Sheet1!C2="So does the cat.", 1, 0)
```

These formulas look to see if the text in those cells is correct. If it is, it returns 1. If not, it returns 0.

Then you will want to nest those formula in a `SUM` function.

```
=SUM(IF(Sheet1!A2="My dog has fleas.", 1,0), IF(Sheet1!C2="So does the cat.", 1, 0))
```

This formula sums (adds) the results of the `IF` statements. You can nest more `IF` statements for additional checks.

```
=SUM(IF(Sheet1!A2="My dog has fleas.", 1,0), IF(Sheet1!A3="The fish swims.", 1, 0), IF(Sheet1!C2="So does the cat.", 1, 0), IF(Sheet1!C3="The cow moos.", 1, 0))
```